# How do I generate GRANTs in Liquibase?

Tags: db2, liquibase

I have an existing DB2 (10.5.0) project I am migrating to Liquibase (3.4.1), and I want to export my existing schema.

However it is skipping the GRANTs. How do I get those?

Also when I create new tables, indices etc, how can I add GRANT to a role within my changeLogFile.xml?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Liquibase does not currently support GRANTs as they are a database-specific concept. You would need to write the GRANT statements using the `<sql>` or `<sqlFile>` change types.

Comment: Any change in that area or is the answer still valid?

Comment: That is still the case. GRANTs are still a database-specific concept, and Liquibase XML is intended to be database agnostic.

Comment: What about this [article](https://www.liquibase.org/blog/automatically-manage-permissions-synonyms-liquibase)? Update: Ah I see they are basically writing an sql file like you pointed out...